# Regarding Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

I am developing a sample using silverlight and prism. I am trying to create a text file in the client side file system from my silverlight application. It is throwing the following error

```
File permission denied.
```

I browsed through internet and came to know that the option "Out of the browser settings needs to be enabled."

But i want to do the operation from my browser (with in browser).

Anybody help in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `SaveFileDialog` class to ask the user to specify a location and file name for the file to be saved.  This requirement is enforced to the protect users from potentially malicious uses of Silverlight.